# Get the number of entries in a bib file with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have single bib file that is shown by single \printbibliography. I would like to use a counter to get the number of entries in a bib file. This counter will be accessed before \printbibliography.

Comment: This code is overengineering to my problem. I look, is there a simpler solution.